# Radgrid column widths not setting in Chrome browser

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, radgrid, column-width

I have problem with rad grid in chrome browser .

column widths am setting in code behind.

In I.E and Firefox it is working fine setting same column width but in chrome it is not setting the widths specified.

It is taking column width based on content in column data.

here is my grid

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="GridHolder" runat="server">

        <telerik:RadGrid ID="goGrid" ClientSettings-Scrolling-UseStaticHeaders="true" MasterTableView-TableLayout="Fixed"  runat="server" OnExcelExportCellFormatting="goGrid_ExcelExportCellFormatting" 
            OnGridExporting="goGrid_GridExporting"  OnItemCommand="goGrid_ItemCommand" OnPdfExporting="goGrid_PdfExporting" 
            OnExcelMLExportRowCreated="goGrid_ExcelMLExportRowCreated">

        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

am adding columns and column width in code behind

```
 sColDef = cColumns.Item(i).ToString
            sField = "GEN_" & i.ToString
            sLabel = goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 2, Chr(1))
            sAlignment = goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 3, Chr(1))
            sWidth = goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 4, Chr(1))
            iDisplayAsIcon = goTR.StringToNum(goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 5, Chr(1)))
            iDisplayAsLink = goTR.StringToNum(goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 6, Chr(1)))
            iTextWidth = goTR.StringToNum(goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 9, Chr(1)))
            iEllipsis = goTR.StringToNum(goTR.ExtractString(sColDef, 10, Chr(1)))

 Dim oField As New GridTemplateColumn

                If sUseOneLine = "1" Then
                    oField.ItemTemplate = New HyperlinkTemplate(sField, iTextWidth, sAlignment, "LIST", sSystemField, Me.ID, Me.gsSelectedRecordID, "GID_ID", gsFile, goTR.StringToNum(sWidth))
                Else
                    oField.ItemTemplate = New HyperlinkTemplate(sField, iTextWidth, sAlignment, "LIST", sSystemField, Me.ID, Me.gsSelectedRecordID, "GID_ID", gsFile, goTR.StringToNum(sWidth), False)
                End If

                If Not goTR.IsFieldCombined(sViewField) And goData.IsFieldSortable(sSystemField, gsFile) Then
                    oField.HeaderTemplate = New HeaderLinkTemplate(Me.ClientID, sSystemField, goView.GetSortFieldIndex(sSystemField), goView.GetSortFieldDirection(sSystemField), sLabel, goTR.StringToNum(sWidth), sAlignment, gbPrintMode, , sUseHeadings = "0")
                Else
                    oField.HeaderTemplate = New HeaderTemplate(sLabel, goTR.StringToNum(sWidth), sAlignment, gbPrintMode, sUseHeadings = "0")
                End If
                oField.HeaderText = sLabel
                'oField.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(goTR.StringToNum(sWidth))
                goGrid.Columns.Add(oField)
```

I tried by setting

```
 oField.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(goTR.StringToNum(sWidth))
                            oField.FilterControlWidth = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(sWidth, UnitType.Pixel)
```

these also but not resolved my issue

Help will be appreciated Please help me thorugh this.

Comment: Did you try setting up the ItemStyle-Width in aspx page for that column

Comment: ya i even tried tat just now ..but no result

Comment: add your aspx code to the question

Comment: ya i added my code just check now . In my .ascx am using both codebehind and html in single page

Comment: did you try setting up the unit pixel value for oField.ItemStyle.Width in code  oField.ItemStyle.Width= Unit.Pixel(goTR.StringToNum(sWidth))

Comment: no ill try now n let u know this

Comment: same problem @sir ram

Comment: try this grdName.MasterTableView.Columns(i).HeaderStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(50)    grdName.MasterTableView.Columns(i).ItemStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(50)

Comment: sorry above lines of code dint work

Comment: did you try'ed in different version of chrome ? cause i had problem like  this  in chrome(latest version) but not in old version and also check for any javascript reference conflict

Comment: ok @sri ram i ll check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i tried to fix my bug in chrome browser by

```
  <MasterTableView Width="100%" TableLayout="Fixed"></MasterTableView>
```

in rad grid view .

This fixed my issue with widths in Rad Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ItemStyle-Width in aspx like the below code

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="12%" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FilterControlWidth="80%" />
```

**update**

```
grdName.MasterTableView.Columns(i).HeaderStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(50)
grdName.MasterTableView.Columns(i).FilterControlWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(50)
grdName.MasterTableView.Columns(i).ItemStyle.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(50)
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: I have individual column widths not  static column widths ..i think u posted  code for static widths for all columns..